# Is there an algorithm to compute the intersection of tautological classes on the moduli space of genus one curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces

Let $\overline{M}_{1,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) $ be the moduli space of degree 
$d$ genus one curves on $\mathbb{P}^2$ with one marked point. Let 
$L\longrightarrow \overline{M}_{1,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) $ denote the universal 
tangent bundle (i.e. the fibre at each point is the tangent space at the marked point). Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the divisor inside $\overline{M}_{1,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) $  that corresponds to the curve passing through some fixed point. Let $a$ denote the divisor that corresponds to the marked point lying on a given line. Let $B_{d_1, d_2}$ denote the boundary divisors where the marked point lies on the $d_1$ component.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is there a formula for the Chern class $c_1(L)$ in terms 
of $\mathcal{H}$, $a$ and $B_{d_1, d_2}$? Moreover, is it possible to compute the 
intersections numbers $c_1(L)^{n_1}\cdot \mathcal{H}^{n_2} \cdot a^{n_3}$ 
evaluated on $[\overline{M}_{1,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)]$?

$\textbf{Remark:}$ Suppose I asked the same question about $\overline{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) $, the moduli space of genus zero curves. Then what I am asking is very well understood as shown in the paper by Pandharipande

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1999-351-04/S0002-9947-99-01909-1/S0002-9947-99-01909-1.pdf

One of the ways one can compute $c_1(L)$ is as follows: one goes to a covering 
space of $\overline{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) $ where one throws in two extra marked points $y_1$ and $y_2$ and we require the marked points to lie on two 
generic lines. It is then easy to construct a section of the pullback of 
$L$, given by 
$$ \frac{(y_1-y_2) dy}{(y-y-1)(y-y_2)}. $$ 
Here $y$ is the original marked point and $y_1$ and $y_2$ 
are the two new marked points.  This section is well defined (invariant under mobius transformations) 
and hence the zeros minus the poles give us the Chern class. Finally 
we get a formula for the Chern class and then one can compute the relevant 
intersection numbers. This is what is done in this paper by Eleny Ionel (Lemma 2.7, page 28).

http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9608030v1.pdf

I am wondering if there is a similar way one can construct such a section 
(either by going to some appropriate cover or by taking an appropriate 
power of the bundle) in the case of $\overline{M}_{1,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$. 
If so, one can just look at the zeros and poles of that section and 
compute the Chern class.

Comment: $L$ is pulled back from $\overline{\mathcal M}_{1,1}$ and is something like $-1/12$ times the pullback of the boundary divisor from $\overline{\mathcal M}_{1,1}$. Perhaps there is an explicit formula for this, like $\sum_{d_1=0}^d B_{d_1,d-d_1}$?

Comment: @Will: But there should also be terms of the form $\alpha_1 \mathcal{H} + \alpha_2 a + $ the term you are saying (boundary terms). Is there any reason $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ should be zero?

Comment: Yes, because (I think) there is a section of the $12$th inverse power of the bundle that vanishes only on the boundary, so there should be only boundary terms.

Comment: @Will: I see, I didn't know this. Hopefully someone will give a reference for this; this is precisely what I was looking for, an explicit section of the line bundle (rather a power of the line bundle).

Comment: The intersection numbers you're asking about are the elliptic GW invariants of $\mathbf P^2$ with gravitational descendents. These are for sure known for a long time. I am not sure what is the right reference but you could start by looking through papers of Zinger.

Comment: On a related note, the space $\overline M_{1,1}(\mathbf P^2,d)$ is singular with boundary components of excess dimension. So you should either make sure to talk of the virtual class, or (which is possible in your case) look instead at the reduced elliptic Gromov--Witten invariants, which are obtained by integrating over the closure of the space of smooth curves. The reduced and nonreduced elliptic GW invariants aren't equal but they contain the same information.

Comment: After some googling, you could look at the paper of Graber-Kock-Pandharipande.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks; I will look at that paper.

Comment: If only calculation of specific numbers are concerned, you can use GROWI software to calculate any GW of projective space.

Comment: @Tehrani: Could you elaborate a bit more on this comment? Where can I find this software and instructions on how to use it? Ideally, I would like to compute these numbers and understand what is going on. For example, the comment Will Sawin made; that $12$ looks like the number of singular cubics. I would like to know the reason behind that. I can share my email address, if you want to explain something in greater detail (for some reason exchanging too many comments is discouraged on mathoveflow).

Comment: @Tehrani: Let me elaborate a bit more; in his second comment Will Sawin indicates that there is some section of L^{12} that vanishes only on the boundary. I actually want to see what that section is (sort of in the same spirit as what Ionel does in her paper).